# Show sequential characterisation of closure from some definition of the closure of a subset

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a metric space and $A \subset E$.

The closure of $A$ is defined as: $\bar{A} := \underset{F \textrm{ closed subset} \\ A  \subset F}{\bigcap} F$

Starting from this definition, how can I show that $x \in \bar{A}$ iff there exists a sequence $(x_k)$ with values in $A$ which converges towards x?

I don't see how I can use the definition to make a link with any sequence. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
For me, a closed set is the complementary of an open set.
An open set is a set which is a vicinity of each of its elements.

Comment: I feel something strange with your question. The sequence characterization works for metric spaces, but your definition of closure does not  looks that has nothing to do with metric spaces.

Comment: I precised things in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKETCH: Suppose first that $x\in E\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$; then there is a closed set $F$ such that $A\subseteq F$ and $x\notin F$. Use this to show that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $A\cap B(x,\epsilon)=\varnothing$ and conclude that no sequence in $A$ can converge to $x$. This will show that if $x$ is the limit of a sequence in $A$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$.

It remains to show that if $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, then there is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$. Let $\epsilon>0$; $E\setminus B(x,\epsilon)$ is a closed set. If $A\subseteq E\setminus B(x,\epsilon)$, we would have $x\in\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq E\setminus B(x,\epsilon)$, which is absurd. Thus, $A\nsubseteq E\setminus B(x,\epsilon)$, and therefore $A\cap B(x,\epsilon)\ne\varnothing$. This is true for every $\epsilon>0$, so for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in A\cap B\left(x,\frac1n\right)$; now consider the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$.